# Sortable/Orderable list - draggable reset() functionality

Tags: drag-and-drop, sencha-touch, draggable

I am implementing sortable/dorderable list functionality with Sencha Touch 2.0 . I am trying to replicate the functionality as it were in Sencha Touch 1.1 with [Ext.util.Sortable](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Sortable) class.

I am almost successful in getting the similar functionality with dragging around and with movement of other list items. However, in Sencha 1.1, there is a draggable.reset() functionality which mostly updates the boundaries as well as resets the offsets. I am unable to replicate this reset functionality with Sencha 2.0 draggable behavior.

Any ideas how to implement that? Following is the code in Sencha 1.1:

```
// We reset the draggable (initializes all the new start values)
    draggable.reset();

// Move the draggable to its current location (since the transform is now 
// different)
    draggable.moveTo(region.left, region.top);
```

I changed moveTo() function with this:

```
draggable._element.setXY([region.left, region.top]);
```

But not the reset() functionality. I have tried to set the `-webkit-transform` directly to the draggable element but somehow that style isn't getting added to that element. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The reset() function is no longer required - just changed the record index in the Dataview store and refreshed the dataview in "dragend" event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do as shown in this example..

http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/tap-and-drag-animation-domination-part-3-of-3-implementing-drag-and-drop-in-sencha-touch-2/